# java jar - how do I specify where resources should be saved?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Here's my current `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.elte.inf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThesisMVN</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main/Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I need the structure of my resources folder (and its subfolders) maintained, as currently takes them out of resources folder, so my game can't start because it can't find all the textures.
resource structure within the project
[image: resource structure within the project]
jar-ed resource structure (note that only one `effects` folder is in the jar, it put the images next to the class file here)
[image: jar-ed resource structure]

Here's how I'm currently loading Images

```java
public class ResourceLoader {
    public static Image getResource(String path){
        Image img=null;
        try{
           img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found("+path+')');
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

The `path` passed to getResource is acquired from an enum where I set the path of all of my Images, like this:

```java
...
BULLET("src/main/resources/bullet.png"),
BULLET_GREY("src/main/resources/bullet_grey.png"),
...
AOE_SLOW("src/main/resources/effects/aoeSlow.png"),
AOE_DISARM("src/main/resources/effects/aoeDisarm.png"),
...
```

I assume I should drop the `src/main/resources` prefixes, but then I can onyl reach the Images once the project is jarred up.

This may be the wonky part of my setup but I'm currently storing every loaded Image in a class called `GameStateData`. Whenever I need to create a new `Sprite` I just get the already loaded Image from there, so I only need to load every Image just once when launching the game.

Comment: You might want to look at [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). From that you can use normal Java ClassLoader to find them.

Comment: You "could" create a subfolder in the "resources" folder which acts as you "desired target", for example `resources/resources/...`, then when it's jar'd they'ed all be in the `/resources` folder in the jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need the structure of my resources folder (and its subfolders) maintained

It *IS* maintained. Every file *and directory* in your resources folder has been dutifully copied straight into the jar as the Standard Directory Layout dictates.

The problem is your setup: At 'dev time' you appear to attempt to load from `resources/items/someItem.png` and this doesn't work when your app is jarred up. There are 2 obvious ways this can be happening;

### You're confused about the reason

You're trying to use `new FileInputStream`, `new File`, or otherwise are attempting to load these **as files**. This does not work and cannot work and no amount of futzing with directory structures will ever make it work. In java, file means **file** - and a png entry in a jarfile is not itself a file.

The way to load such resources is, always, this strategy:

1. Pick a class that is the 'source location' - as in, the resource you're looking for will be where-ever the JVM found this class file. Generally you can pick any class in your entire application; this is relevant only when you use modularized class loading systems. If you don't know what that means, you're not using those.
2. Call `MyContextClass.class.getResource(resourceKey)` to obtain a URL object, which you can then pass to whatever API allows you to do that (and lots of APIs do, notably including swing's own `ImageIcon`). Alternatively, use `try (var in = MyContextClass.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceKey) { /* use resource here */ }` - this is the one to use if the API in question doesn't have an overload that takes a URL but does have one that takes an InputStream. This is also the one to use if you want to directly read the contents.
3. `resourceKey` comes in 2 flavours. There's `"foo/bar.png"` which resolves a path relative to the exact **package** your context class is in. If you have `package com.foo; public class Bar {}` then somewhere in the deployment there's `com/foo/Bar.class`. For example, in a jar file, or in a `bin` dir. If you then write `Bar.class.getResource("baz/quux.png")`, and Bar.class was in that jar file, then the system is going to look in the same jar file, for `com/foo/baz/quux.png`. Alternatively, include a leading slash: `"/foo/bar.png"` would look in the same jar, but for `foo/bar.png`.
4. That's all you have to do. Build systems and IDEs ensure that you put your images exactly where you have them now (in a `resources` folder), you **do not** include `resources` in your deployment key (for the same reason you have your java source files in `src/main/java/com/foo/MyApp.class`, and you do not include `src`, `main`, or `java` in your fully qualified class names. It's just `com.foo.MyApp`, not `main.java.com.foo.MyApp`. The `resources` isn't a part of it any more than `java` is a part of your class names. If it doesn't work you've misconfigured them.

### You've got a wonky setup

It's possible you've been hacking away and e.g. using a plugin system where you check for certain files either directly on the filesystem yourself, -OR- load via `ContextClass.class.getResource`, or you've been messing with the way your IDE's maven plugin identifies resource directories, or you've been handrolling the setup of your IDE projects (instead of using its maven integration) and marked `src/main` as source dir (instead of `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`). The setup is broken; fix that (do not 'fix' it by trying to keep `resources` around).

Comment: I updated the question with my Image loading and runtime Image storage methods. How should I modify the `path`s and my `getResource` method so I can still load and store every Image in `GameStateData`? Should I make a getResource class in `Effects` for example just to get its package prefix?

Comment: As I said, `new File` __CANNOT POSSIBLY__ read anything from jars, ever. You can't use that, you must use `.getResource`. Really, just.. read my answer and do what it says, not sure what more you want. With the proper project setup it'll work right from the IDE _AND_ from the JAR, in the same way, no problem. Yes, strip src/main/resources out, as I said.